# Как убрать визуальное выделение ячейки в QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4

Необходимо убрать визуальное выделение у таблицы QTableWidget, как это можно сделать? если применить:

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(parent);
table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

То в этой таблице нельзя будет перемещать объекты, но перемещать объекты необходимо!

Хотел установить прозрачность для этого "селектора" но он перекрасился в серый цвет.

```
setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0%);");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке отображен этот "селектор" если можно так выразиться.

Comment: QTableWidget::item{ selection-background-color: white}

Comment: @awesome спустя столько времени появился ответ) можешь написать его как ответ, я отмечу.